# How background limitation applied onResume state activity?

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-8.0-oreo

I created a service in which all activities of the app are updated with server directly.
For e.g. Recyclerview is update whenever new data added in adapter by the Service class(not by activity).

But i read from stackoverflow and many other resources but i cant understand properly , that in API 26 android destroy the background service when user leave the app.(i might be wrong).

So, will this background service update activities when user stand within app(user didn't exit from the app) in android o ? 
In other words when BG(background) service kill ?

1. service start by Mainactivity...load on ram & battery...than kill BG service(no matter user within app or outside of app) or
2. service start by Mainactivity...user leave the app ...load on ram & battery...than kill BG service

Comment: If your app is offscreen with no foreground service, your app is "in the background". Once placed in the background, Android O+ will let you start/run a service for a certain amount of time -- a few minutes. It will forcibly terminate your app, without warning, if you exceed that limit. If your app returns to the foreground, you're fine; those restrictions go away.

Comment: Is it necessary to create notification for foreground service , even when app is in running mode?

Comment: It is necessary to have a notification whenever the foreground service is actually _running_. Think of it as android's way of preventing malicious apps from snooping about in the background too long, gathering data on the user without their knowledge. Now, if you want to stop the foreground service when the user re-enters the app, then that's up to you.

Comment: no i want keep continuous service when user enters in the app w/o notification... Is is possible ?

Comment: Indeed it is. I said you earlier that you could stop the service. But you can also just call [`stopForeground()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#stopForeground(boolean)), which takes a `removeNotification` parameter. This leaves the service running, but changes it from a foreground service to a regular service. You can switch back and forth like this.

Comment: please call in PM